# How to scale activejob-google_cloud_pubsub worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-pubsub, rails-activejob, app-engine-flexible

#### Overview

I have a Rails ActiveJob that uses the gem [activejob-google_cloud_pubsub](https://github.com/ursm/activejob-google_cloud_pubsub). ([Short usage tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-ruby-rails-activejob-pubsub)). My application is deployed to AppEngine on a ruby flex environment. While my application works as expected, I am having difficulty scaling the worker services that consume the messages from Google Cloud PubSub. The gem's README docs mention a way to specify a Worker's max_threads from the terminal but not from within the rails app. As I am reading the gem's source code I see the `initialize` for the worker takes in that variable `max_threads` (which default to the number of cores). The problem is that I don't see how to initialize the worker with a default configuration so I can increase the thread number.

#### Questions Summary:

1 - How to initialize the `activejob-google_cloud_pubsub` Worker with a higher number of threads?

2 - Would it be unadvisable to initialize the worker with more threads than processors in the machine?

#### Other Details:

- I am deploying the worker on a separate service from the Rails Server by using a worker.yaml apart from the app.yaml
- The worker service is being scaled manually to 3 instances, still this are barely handling 10 messages per second (lean message processor, only log to output and return)

***Any Input into how I can scale this type of queue processing would be helpful.***

Comment: Was any of the links in my answer useful? Do you have the same performance issue?

Comment: @Juancki, while your answer does provide links to useful resources on the topic of scaling and multithreading with rails, it does not answer the main technical question regarding the `activejob-google_cloud_pubsub` gem. I have found an answer that is more direct and will submit it. Thanks for  the resource links :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Please consider marking your response as correct. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - How to initialize the activejob-google_cloud_pubsub Worker with a higher number of threads?

**worker.yaml**

Add the terminal flag `--max_threads` as described in the [gem's README](https://github.com/ursm/activejob-google_cloud_pubsub)

```
runtime: ruby
env: flex
service: <xxx>
entrypoint: bundle exec activejob-google_cloud_pubsub-worker --max_threads=5
...
```

This should create 5 worker threads in every instance. The default is the number of logical cores.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the number of Messages per second that you will be able to serve can be increased with:

- [More computing power](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml):

  - Increasing the number of instances. `instances: 5`
  - Increasing the number of cpu per instances. `cpu: 4`
- [Concurrency on Ruby on Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html)
- Decrease the computation needed per reuqest:

  - Debug your code using the [Debugging an Instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/debugging-an-instance#enabling_and_disabling_debug_mode)
  - And then, monitor the code performance with [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs)

For fine grained performance of computing resources I would suggest checking the [Scaling App.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/reference/app-yaml#services) and use `automatic_scaling` to scale your computing power to the load during peak hours.